# How to enable iSCSI MPIO Round Robin on ESXi 7

Tags: vmware-esxi, synology

I'm running the free version of ESXi and a Synology's iSCSI SAN for storage. Synology details setting up Round Robin load balancing in the final step of their guide to setting up MPIO here:
https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_Use_iSCSI_Targets_on_VMware_ESXi_Server_with_Multipath_Support

But they appear to be using the vSphere Client which I cannot find anymore. I cannot find where to enable Round Robin in ESXi's web ui.

I would also prefer to avoid using a trial of vCenter Server to configure this as I'll be stuck if I need to reconfigure it after 60 days.

Unfortunately, LACP did not provide additional bandwidth for me like this post describes: [Synology and vmware with 4 way MPIO slow iSCSI speeds](https://serverfault.com/questions/955145/synology-and-vmware-with-4-way-mpio-slow-iscsi-speeds#new-answer?newreg=752cdf6b7dd241b0848ac5d364a5b40b)

With a dynamic initiator, I'm seeing 12 connections in the Synology SAN manager (3 ifs on the Syno, 4 on the Hypervisor) but disk speeds are still capping out at 1gbps and there is no traffic going over the other 2 interfaces on the Syno.

(Edit)
Network:

- DS1520+ with 4 gigabit ethernet ports, 3 used for iSCSI
- Dell Server with 5 gigabit ethernet ports, 4 used for iSCSI
- 7 iSCSI connections directly to a GS724Tv4 switch on VLAN30
- The first on each server is on VLAN40 and not used for iSCSI
- EdgeRouter 4 is also connected to the switch for internet access using .1q for all VLANs on the switch.

Comment: Please describe your cabling and network topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change MPIO settings in ESXi web ui directly. You can only add/remove static or dynamic targets. However, you can enable Round Robin using CLI by directly  connecting to the ESXi host. Here's an article on this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2000552. Otherwise, it's vSphere Web Client (vCenter). As far as I can tell, RR should help as by default you'll have only a single path active for IO which will be limiting the performance. However, take into the account your drives speed in Synology. It can also be a bottleneck (I doubt but it's possible).

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not the case, you can do it via the web client - see this; https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc/GUID-AE95818C-0782-429B-9526-DF12673A63C7.html#GUID-AE95818C-0782-429B-9526-DF12673A63C7

Comment: is there a way to get it to persist after reboots?

Comment: @Chopper3 the article you mentioned describes the process of changing MPIO in vSphere Web Client which means vCenter. You cannot do this in ESXi host Web UI directly.

Comment: @charlespick I would expect the change to be persistent after reboot. Have you tried it and it reverts back to default?

Comment: @Strepsils Yeah in esxtop it's very clear that it's only using 1 interface after reboot.

Comment: @Strepsils - If you really wanted you could just build a vCSA on the evaluation licence just for this and then delete it.

Comment: @Chopper3 I don't want to be stuck if I need to reconfigure it later. After the evaluation runs out on the esxi host, you can't link a new vcenter server even if that vcenter is within it's evaluation period.